# Compute moving average for all entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, `Measures`, with columns: `timestamp` (Unix timestamp), `tag`, `value`.
To get a single moving average of say, 15 days, I can do something like:

```
SELECT tag,avg(value) 
FROM measures 
 WHERE tag='xtr' 
 AND timestamp<1353304800
 AND timestamp>1350622800 
 GROUP BY tag;
```

Now I want to get the moving average of the 150 latest rows, but I'm not sure how to query it.

```
SELECT t, s,avg(bv) 
FROM 
  (SELECT A.timestamp as t,A.tag as ta,A.value as ac, B.timestamp as tb,B.value as bv, 
  FROM measures 
  CROSS JOIN measures B 
  WHERE A.tag='xtr' AND B.tag='xtr' 
  GROUP BY A.tag) WHERE ROWNUM <= 150;
```

This is obviously wrong, but I've been thinking about it and cant figure it out. Any ideas?
My train of thought is that I need to match each entry with the 150 entries below it and compute the `value` average for those 150 entries. I'm also pretty sure that there's probably a better way without a `CROSS JOIN`, as that would be very slow.

Comment: Which RDBMS? They all have different capabilities.  Ones that have implemented `LAG()` make this *relatively* painless.  Others need extremely ineffective code, and that often makes it more worth while doing in the application than in SQL.

Comment: My approach, still use a join (parent = day, slaves values of that day) and select the rownumber for that parent values in addition. Use that rownum for group by over your avg(). Should give you a decent speed - edit sorry ;) no Oracle DB at hand here.

Comment: Oracle has many different versions, do you know which version you are on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not entirely clear what your table structure and uniqueness of data is, but this query will give you a true moving average of the previous 150 rows (inclusive of current row) for all timestamps.

```
SELECT
  tag,
  timestamp,
  avg(value) over (partition by tag
                   order by timestamp asc
                   rows between 149 preceding and current row) moving_avg
FROM
  measures 
WHERE
  tag='xtr'
```

If you just need to isolate the most recent 150 rows then base your query on:

```
select
  tag,
  value
from(
  select tag
         value
  from measures
  order by timestamp desc)
where
  rownum <= 150
```

Comment: You need an `order by timestamp` in the analytic function, otherwise yes; the easiest way to generate the moving average.

Comment: Works great, and it's pretty fast too. Thanks. I wasn't thinking of using partitions at all. Learning new things every day :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY timestamp) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    measures
)
SELECT
  measure.tag,
  measure.timestamp,
  AVG(history.value)
FROM
  sequenced           AS measure
INNER JOIN
  sequenced           AS history
    ON  history.tag          = measure.tag
    AND history.sequence_id >  measure.sequence_id - 150
    AND history.sequence_id <= measure.sequence_id
GROUP BY
  measure.tag,
  measure.timestamp
```

Not very efficient, every row gets joined on 150 other rows.  But it's the simplest way of approaching it that I know of that most *(relatively recent)* versions of ORACLE will support.

Comment: Is there a special reason why (since you're using analytic functions anyway) you not simply use avg() over (partition by ... rows between ...), as suggested by David Aldrige?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has Packages, with the usage of packages you can write your own moving average function.

I don't have enough time to test the application but in theory it should work (only for oracle)

"Variables declared in Package Bodies will live (keep their value) during whole session."

```
Create or replace package xxx ;
procedure clearMovingAverage ;
function movingAverage (newAVG in number) return number ;
end ;
/

create or replace package body xxx ;
movTot number ;
movCnt number ;
procedure clearMovingAverage is 
begin
  movTot := 0 ;
  movCnt := 0 ;
end ;
function movingAverage (newAvg in number) return number is 
begin
  if newAvg is not null then 
     movTot := movTot + newAvg ;
     movCnt := movCnt + 1 ;
  end if ;
  return movTot / movCnt ;
end ;
end ;
/
```

usage:

```
begin
  xxx.clearMovingAverage ;
  select tag,xxx.movingAverage(avg(value)) 
    FROM measures 
  ..... 
   group by tag ;
end ;
```

or

```
begin
  xxx.clearMovingAverage ;
  select tag, xxx.MovingAverage(avgValue) 
    from (select tag,avg(value) avgValue 
          FROM measures 
          ..... 
          group by tag)
end ;
```

Hope that this code will help...